# Scroll position returns zero when height is set to 100%

Tags: jquery

I've got `html`, `body` and `.wrapper` set to `height:100%;`... this is for various full screen functionality. As a result there's a knock on effect on trying to get the viewport position in that it always returns as zero.

When I remove the 100% height it returns the expected results but obviously this breaks other functionality.

How can I get around this? Is there a way to keep the height 100%?

```
function get(){
  $('.position').html(
    $('html, body, .wrapper').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()
  );
}

get();
$(window).scroll(get);
```

Html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="position"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Css

```
html,
body,
.wrapper {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example?
If the scroll is happening in your .wrapper instead of the window, you can use the scrollTop property of the .wrapper

Comment: @MisterJ I'll pad the question out now... it still returns zero when I just use `.wrapper`, as soon as I take off the `height:100%` it returns the expected numbers.

Comment: Really not  clear what you are trying to accomplish. Create a demo that outlines your issue

Comment: @charlietfl trying to get the current viewport position when scrolling down a page when the parent elements are all set to `height:100%;`

Comment: @Rob I didn't say to use wrapper for .offset().top, but for the scrollTop itself. 
Though as charlietfl said but now edited, without any overflow there is no scroll position to be found. So I assumed that your wrapper was overflowing, thus you should be able to get its inner scroll position with $('.wrapper').scrollTop() ?

Comment: I agree...it's probably not the window that is scrolling due to the 100% height. Create a demo that outlines your issue

Comment: @MisterJ Aha! I get you, with some slight tweaks I've got it. It's now giving me a number... thanks both very much. Feel free to put an answer (or I will).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `html`, `body` and `.wrapper` are 100% height, in turn the scrollTop for the `window` will always be 0.

Though you can instead use scrollTop on the `.wrapper` component.